# Passing Optional List argument from Django to filter with in Raw SQL

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, sql-in, rawsql

When using primitive types such as Integer, I can without any problems do a query like this:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql='''SELECT count(*) FROM account 
        WHERE %(pk)s ISNULL OR id %(pk)s''', params={'pk': 1})
```

Which would either return row with `id = 1` or it would return *all* rows if `pk` parameter was equal to `None`.

However, when trying to use similar approach to pass a *list/tuple* of IDs, I always produce a SQL syntax error when passing empty/None tuple, e.g. trying:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql='''SELECT count(*) FROM account 
        WHERE %(ids)s ISNULL OR id IN %(ids)s''', params={'ids': (1,2,3)})
```

works, but passing `()` produces SQL syntax error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: SELECT count(*) FROM account WHERE () ISNULL OR id IN ()
```

Or if I pass `None` I get:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 1: ...LECT count(*) FROM account WHERE NULL ISNULL OR id IN NULL
```

I tried putting the argument in SQL in `()` - `(%(ids)s)` - but that always breaks one or the other condition. I also tried playing around with `pg_typeof` or casting the argument, but with no results.

Notes:

- the actual SQL is much more complex, this one here is a simplification for illustrative purposes
- as a last resort - I could alter the SQL in Python based on the argument, but I *really* wanted to avoid that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I had an idea of using just 1 argument, but replacing it with a dummy value `[-1]` and then using it like

```
cursor.execute(sql='''SELECT ... WHERE -1 = any(%(ids)s) OR id = ANY(%(ids)s)''', params={'ids': ids if ids else [-1]})
```

but this did a *Full table scan for non empty lists*, which was unfortunate, so a no go.

Then I thought I could do a little preprocessing in python and send 2 arguments instead of just the single list- the actual list and an empty list boolean indicator. That is

```
cursor.execute(sql='''SELECT ... WHERE %(empty_ids)s = TRUE OR id = ANY(%(ids)s)''', params={'empty_ids': not ids, 'ids': ids})
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it performs quite well (Index scan for non empty list, Full table scan for empty list - but that returns the whole table anyway, so it's ok)

And **finally** I came up with the simplest solution and quite elegant:

```
cursor.execute(sql='''SELECT ... WHERE '{}' = %(ids)s OR id = ANY(%(ids)s)''', params={'ids': ids})
```

This one also performs Index scan for non empty lists, so it's quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

From the [psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html):

> Note You can use a Python list as the argument of the IN operator using the PostgreSQL ANY operator.

```
ids = [10, 20, 30]
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))
```

Furthermore ANY can also work with empty lists, whereas IN () is a SQL syntax error.

Comment: Well, this doesn't really answer the question - I need the query constructed in such a way, that if the list is empty (or modified in python in some way instead of being "empty"), it will return all rows (as if the condition weren't there at all) - see the first query example for primitive arguments such as int

Comment: But I'll upvote, since it lead me to my current solution.